# What specialty of doctor should one see for recurrent fungal skin infections?

Tags: dermatology, jock-itch-tinea-cruris, ringworm

For recurrent tinea (jock itch), what specialty of physician should one see - a primary care physician, dermatologist, or infectious disease physician?

Answer (score 1):

You can always start with a primary care physician.  Tinea is common, and there are multiple ways to treatment tinea infections that do not require a specialist.  A dermatologist might be warranted for extensive, invasive, multiple-treatment-resistant cases.  In which case the patient's immune system needs to be called into question (e.g. diabetes, HIV).  Infectious disease doctors are overkill for tinea, but the correct choice for HIV.